# Find Fourier transform of triangular function based on a Fourier results of rectangular

Tags: fourier-analysis, transformation, signal-processing

I have a triangular pulse given by
$$x\left(\frac{t}T\right) =
\begin{cases}
1-\frac {|t|}T,  & \text{if $T\ge t$} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Given that $F\left(\operatorname{rect}\left(\frac{t}T\right)\right)=T\operatorname{sinc}(fT)$

where $F$ denotes a Fourier transformation

$$\operatorname{rect}\left(\frac{t}T\right)=\begin{cases}
1,  &  \frac{T}{2} \ge t \ge \frac{-T}{2} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

> Prove that $F\left(x\left(\frac{t}T\right)\right)=T\operatorname{sinc}^2(fT)$.

As my knowledge, I prove above equation is $T^2\operatorname{sinc}^2(fT)$, instead of $T\operatorname{sinc}^2(fT)$.

We have
$x\left(\frac{t}T\right)=\operatorname{rect}\left(\frac{t}T\right)*\operatorname{rect}\left(\frac{t}T\right)$
Then
\begin{align}
F\left(x\left(\frac{t}T\right)\right) & =F\left(\operatorname{rect}\left(\frac{t}T\right)\right)\cdot F\left(\operatorname{rect}\left(\frac{t}T\right)\right)\\
& =T \operatorname{sinc}(fT) \cdot T \operatorname{sinc}(fT) =T^2\operatorname{sinc}^2(fT).
\end{align}

What is wrong in my solution? How to correct it?

Comment: Do you also have $\operatorname{sinc}^2(fT)$ instead of $\operatorname{sinc}^2(f)$? Also, what is $f$?

Comment: Sorry. It must be $fT$. I corrected it

Comment: $f$ is frequency  in Fourier domain

Answer (score 0):

For $t=0$, we have $x(t/T)=1$ but $\operatorname{rect}(t/T)*\operatorname{rect}(t/T)=T$. This, and the difference between your answer and the correct one, should give you a hint of what is wrong.

Comment: Could you based on my solution and correct it. I have no idea to prove my problem